# Is there a generic term for working with files and directories?

Tags: files, directory, terminology

I was wondering if there is a generic term that describes working with or manipulating files and directories that includes all the different ways of manipulating files?
Similar to the term coding that describes the process of creating or writing a program with some sort of programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"File management".

This includes moving files around, copying them, organising them into directories, removing files and directories, etc.

It is the types of tasks that a user may perform using the standard commands `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, `mkdir`, `rmdir` etc., or with special [*file managers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager), such as Natilus ([GNOME Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files)) or [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander).
A file manager might allow you to work with single files or directories but may also allow you to do file management operations on files and directories in batches, possibly over networks.